# How can I serilise interface PGNotification?

Tags: java, serialization, interface

In my current project, I am using org.postgresql.PGNotification to obtain notifications from postgres. The usage is like this : PGNotification notifications[] = pgconn.getNotifications();

But just recently I realised PGNotification is not a class but an interface!  If I wish to serialise PGNotification, how do I do it? In the IDE it automatically generated the following code, which is most likely not the code that can work.

Essentially, it is that I don't understand how can an interface be used like above. Can some one explain it to me?

Thanks!

```
public class SerializableNotification implements Serializable, PGNotification{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1601340490113080932L;

    public String getName() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    public int getPID() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    public String getParameter() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: Why do you want to serialize PGNotification Interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably need to convert your `PGNotification` objects into `SerializableNotification` objects.
Something like this:

```
PGNotification[] notifications = pgconn.getNotifications();
SerializableNotification[] serializableNotifications = new SerializableNotification[notifications.length];
for(int i = 0; i < notifications.length; i++) {
   PGNotification notif = notifications[i];
   serializableNotifications[i] = new SerializableNotification(notif.getName(), notif.getPID, notif.getParameter());
}
```

Given that `SerializableNotification` is code that you own, you could simply create a constructor to receive `name`, `PID` and `Parameter`.

Answer (score 0):

In general when we talk about serialization we mean that the **state** of the object will be serialized.

However interfaces in Java do not have states. They just define a contract of all possible implementations by means of methods declarations. The decision about the actual implementation of the interface in this case is not in your hands (you can't count on a concrete implementation because in future versions of postgres Java driver this may change).

So if you look at this issue from this perspective you should understand that technically its impossible and wrong. Generalizing all above, its a bad idea to serialize an abstraction that wasn't meant for seralization.

Instead I would ask myself a question why do I want to serialize this? Probably you want to get some data and try to serialize it? In this case it can be done but then think about deserialization (when, what to do with a deserialized object, etc).

Comment: Thanks for the comment! Yesterday I have realised what you are talking about and yes I have created a new serialisable object containing the parameters in the PGNotification interface and tried to transfer it. However, you didn't answer my question, that how can an interface be used like: PGNotification notifications[] = pgconn.getNotifications(); where each notification instance is actually carrying values? Given that PGNotification is an interface, not an object.